# Updating outcome of a select query?

Tags: sql, oracle, select

I am trying to update certain pieces of data based on a select statement within a trigger. The select statement is as follows:

```
SELECT col1 
FROM tbl1 d 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl2 e ON D.colid = E.colid
```

I then want to change the data returned from this statement to a new value calculated in the trigger. I thought it might be something like this `e.col1 = COUNTER` but that doesn't seem to work. Any help with updating this data would be great, thanks.

EDIT: I've changed the select query to retrieve the data I actually want. The one I stated above was wrong.

```
UPDATE tbl2 SET col1 = COUNTER
WHERE EXISTS(SELECT col1
FROM tbl1 d 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl2 e ON D.colid = E.colid 
    WHERE col2= :new.col2);
```

I should state again that the problem is when using the code above is that the whole column in the table is updated as opposed to the data returned by the select query.

EDIT: 
tbl1 contains columns colid, col2 and

tbl2 contains columns colid, col1

Trigger is before insert on tbl1.

Comment: Define: `certain pieces of data`. Clarify: `want to change the return the data returned all to a new value calculated in the trigger`.

Comment: certain pieces of data - a column of a select query. And I meant that I wanted to change the certain pieces of data from the query to a value which I have previously calculated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would help if you'd told us which table the trigger was on, what kind of trigger, and what columns are in what table. I still can't quite figure out what you're trying to do with these updates.

```
UPDATE tbl2 SET col1 = COUNTER
WHERE EXISTS(SELECT col1
FROM tbl1 d 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl2 e ON D.colid = E.colid 
    WHERE col2= :new.col2);
```

I think the problem is that you are doing a `LEFT JOIN` in your inner select statement. Since there will always be a row in the inner query and you're doing this in an `EXISTS` clause, it will always match a row, and your `UPDATE` will fire on every row in the table.

Maybe this will work better for you:

```
UPDATE tbl2 SET col1 = COUNTER
WHERE EXISTS(SELECT col1
FROM tbl1 d 
    INNER JOIN tbl2 e ON D.colid = E.colid 
    WHERE col2= :new.col2);
```

I will say that if this trigger is on tbl2, then this is a bad way of doing this, because you're likely to run into the mutating table problem.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I tried the join you said and it didn't compile with the error invalid table name. Yeah sorry that was stupid of me; I have added the additional information that you requested.

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to use a MERGE statement with a WHEN MATCHED CLAUSE. Here's a good example : http://www.oracle-developer.net/display.php?id=203

Answer (score 0):

Because you are aliasing your tbl2 table in the subquery it is treating it as a different table not related tot he update.  No need to do an exists just join the update tot he table and it will only update where there is an inner join

[my SQL Server not oracle so might be slightly different syntax]

```
update tbl2  
set col1 = (COUNTER)
from tbl2 t2
where tbl2.colid = t2.colid
```

Comment: I've changed what I need the query to do and I believe that I have to use the select now because I have the where statement which references col2 which belongs to tbl1.

Answer (score 0):

I am a little confused by the question, but I *guess* this may be what you want:

```
UPDATE tbl2
SET    col1 = COUNTER
WHERE  EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM   tbl1
    WHERE  tbl1.colid = tbl2.colid
    AND    tbl1.col2 = :new.col2);
```

There is also the (non-standard) feature of Oracle to apply an [`UPDATE` to columns of a subquery expression](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_10008.htm#SQLRF01708).
[This pages demonstrates the feature](http://geekswithblogs.net/WillSmith/archive/2008/06/18/oracle-update-with-join-again.aspx).

Could work for you:

```
UPDATE (
    SELECT tbl2.col1
    FROM   tbl2
    JOIN   tbl1 USING (colid)
    WHERE  tbl1.col2 = :new.col2
    ) t
SET  tbl2.col1 = COUNTER;
```